# KVM-QEMU-SPICE: drag 'n drop files from guest to host?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, virt-manager, spice

Spice's guest tools work well for file transfers from host to guest, but don't work from guest to host. Spice's Webdav extension is a good workaround, but it has drawbacks (doesn't work from virt-manager viewer).

Clipboard works in both directions, so why not file transfers? Have I missed something or has there been no solution so far?